# mysqli strange errors 1064, when there is no syntax errors

Tags: php, mysqli

can anyone please assist me, that whats wrong i m doing. There is no syntax error in the php code, but output is- connection successful
Table customers NOT created. Error: 1064
Table stats NOT created. Error : 1005. I am using XAMPP, with PHP 7

```
      <?php


      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

      if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Connect failed%\n".mysqli_connect_errno();
          exit();
      }

      else {
      echo "connection successful";
      }

      $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (

      P_Id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Firstname(100) varchar NOT NULL,
      Lastname(100) varchar NOT NULL,
      Address varchar(500) NOT NULL,
      City varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(P_Id)

      )";

      if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)==1){
          echo "Table customers created successfully";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "<br/>"."Table customers NOT created. Error: ".mysqli_errno($conn);
      }

      $sql2 = 'CREATE TABLE STATS (

      O_Id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Offers varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      Resorts varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
      ArrivalDate date NOT NULL,
      P_Id int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(O_Id),
      FOREIGN KEY(P_Id) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(P_Id)

      )';



      if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)==1){
          echo "Table stats created successfully";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "<br/>"."Table stats NOT created. Error : ".mysqli_errno($conn);
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: luna please check the above comment and start marking the answers now. It will help others too.

Comment: Why people are not marking answers even after there problem is solved. I am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the character limit for `VARCHAR` after the `VARCHAR`keyword. So, for example, in the query for table `CUSTOMERS`, the `Firstname` clause will look like:

```
Firstname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank u so much..ha ha..typing error. Perhaps i need a sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is how you declare your varchar.

```
Firstname(100) varchar NOT NULL,
```

Must be :

```
Firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

So change firstname and lastname syntax and all will work right.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thank u so much..ha ha..typing error. Perhaps i need a sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is column declarations:

You should use: `<name> <type>(length) NOT NULL`